# SQL Query Left Outer Join To Current Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query and I want to look up the values from other table as a reference but not mess up my current query results. I think I have to use a Outer Left Join, but not sure how to incorporate that with my current query.

My current query looks similar to this:

```
SELECT a.primary_key,
       a.phase,
       b.project_number,
       c.LENGTH,
       d.color
  FROM TableA a,
       TableB b,
       TableC c,
       TableD d
 WHERE     c.primary_key = a.PROJECT_ID
       AND b.primary_key = a.PROJECT_ID
       AND b.primary_key = d.project_ID
       AND (c.date IS NULL OR c.number IS NULL)
       AND d.color IN ('black','red','blue')
ORDER BY 1
```

Now, that gives me a table of 50 results. 'TableContacts' has the look up value to my b.project_number. So say my table of 50 results, only 10 of them have b.project_number, I need the lookup values from 'TableContacts' to also show in my results, but I don't want that to affect my results and cut it down to 10, I still need my original 50 results, just with that additional information. Help?

Comment: Get rid of `a,b` implicit joins and use ANSI `JOIN` syntax, all things  will then be clear to you how to solve  it.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expect result.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `CONTACTS` table to your joins:

```
SELECT a.primary_key,
       a.phase,
       b.project_number,
       c.LENGTH,
       d.color, 
       ct.lookup_value --<< this is from the CONTACTS table
FROM TableA a
  JOIN TableB b ON b.primary_key = a.PROJECT_ID
  JOIN TableC c ON c.primary_key = a.PROJECT_ID
  JOIN TableD d ON b.primary_key = d.project_ID
  LEFT JOIN contacts ct ON ct.some_column = b.project_Number --<< this is the outer join to the CONTACTS table
WHERE (c.date IS NULL OR c.number IS NULL)
  AND d.color IN ('black','red','blue')
ORDER BY 1
```

As you obfuscated your table and column names it's hard to guess how exactly the join condition on the `CONTACTS` table should look like.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this approach:

**Create a table with the results of your current query:**

```
create table t1 as 
SELECT a.primary_key,
       a.phase,
       b.project_number,
       c.LENGTH_col,
       d.color
FROM a,b,c,d
WHERE c.primary_key = a.PROJECT_ID
       AND b.primary_key = a.PROJECT_ID
       AND b.primary_key = d.project_ID
       AND (c.date_col IS NULL OR c.number_col IS NULL)
       AND d.color IN ('black','red','blue')
ORDER BY 1;
```

**Use a union to get the desired results:**

```
select t1.primary_key, t1.phase, t1.project_number, t1.length_col, t1.color, TableContacts.lookup_column
from t1, TableContacts
where t1.project_number = TableContacts.project_number
UNION
select t1.primary_key, t1.phase, t1.project_number, t1.length_col, t1.color, null
from t1 where t1.project_number is null;
```

**Illustration by creating dummy data:**

```
select * from a;
PRIMARY_KEY | PROJECT_ID | PHASE
1   100 Phase-1
2   200 Phase-2
3   300 Phase-3
4   400 Phase-4
5   500 Phase-5

select * from b;
PRIMARY_KEY | PROJECT_NUMBER
100 null
200 2000
300 3000
400 null
500 5000

select * from c;
PRIMARY_KEY | NUMBER_COL | LENGTH_COL | DATE_COL
100 null    99  null
200 null    99  null
300 null    99  null
400 null    99  null
500 null    99  null

select * from d;
PROJECT_ID  | COLOR
100 black
200 red
300 blue
400 black
500 yellow

select * from TableContacts;
PROJECT_NUMBER  | LOOKUP_COLUMN
1000    l-1000
2000    l-2000
3000    l-3000
4000    l-4000
5000    l-5000
```

Existing query in question returns this:

```
SELECT a.primary_key,
       a.phase,
       b.project_number,
       c.LENGTH_col,
       d.color
FROM a,b,c,d
WHERE c.primary_key = a.PROJECT_ID
       AND b.primary_key = a.PROJECT_ID
       AND b.primary_key = d.project_ID
       AND (c.date_col IS NULL OR c.number_col IS NULL)
       AND d.color IN ('black','red','blue')
ORDER BY 1;

PRIMARY_KEY | PHASE | PROJECT_NUMBER | LENGTH_COL | COLOR
1   Phase-1 null    99  black
2   Phase-2 2000    99  red
3   Phase-3 3000    99  blue
4   Phase-4 null    99  black
```

The goal is to populate the `lookup_column` where `project_number` is not null. Running the union query provided at start of answer:

```
select t1.primary_key, t1.phase, t1.project_number, t1.length_col, t1.color, TableContacts.lookup_column
from t1, TableContacts
where t1.project_number = TableContacts.project_number
UNION
select t1.primary_key, t1.phase, t1.project_number, t1.length_col, t1.color, null
from t1 where t1.project_number is null;

PRIMARY_KEY | PHASE | PROJECT_NUMBER | LENGTH_COL | COLOR | LOOKUP_COLUMN
1   Phase-1 null    99  black   null
2   Phase-2 2000    99  red     l-2000
3   Phase-3 3000    99  blue    l-3000
4   Phase-4 null    99  black   null
```

Comment: Where would I put this join condition?

Comment: This would be an additional join condition in the WHERE clause to the ones already present in the query.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but it gave me what I had before. Without the extra (+) where clause, I have 872 results, but after adding it, it filters it down to 61 and doesn't include the rows where b.project_number is blank. I don't want to exclude those, I still need my 872 results. Hmmm.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: Updated my answer with some examples of sample data and query outputs.